# Extra legend marker with Legended function

Tags: plotting, legending

When I used Legended function, I got extra unwanted legend marker.

MSW:

```
ListPlot[Legended[Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}, {i, 10}], 
  Placed[LineLegend[{Directive[Thick]}, {"legend"}], {Right, 
  Top}]], Joined -> True]
```

and got the following result:

[image]

Clearly there's an extra blue line. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [`Legended`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Legended.html), the [`ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) is the argument.

```
SeedRandom[6];

Legended[
 ListPlot[
  Table[RandomReal[1, 2], {i, 10}],
  Joined -> True],
 Placed[
  LineLegend[
   {Directive[ColorData[97][1], Thick]}, {"legend"}],
  {Right, Top}]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use the [`PlotLegends`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html) option to [`ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html)

```
SeedRandom[6];

ListPlot[
 Table[RandomReal[1, 2], {i, 10}]
 PlotStyle->Thick,
 Joined -> True,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"legend"}, {Right, Top}]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I can wrap the whole plot as well. This solves my actual problem. But I still can't figure out why when the argument is the data, extra marker appears. Do you know why?

Comment: @Turgon - Because you included two different legends: 1) you `Legended` the argument to `ListPlot`, and 2) you added a `LineLegend`. Note that the first inherited the color of the default `PlotStyle` and the second has the style specified in the `LineLegend`.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you are using seems a bit odd.  From the docs you can wrap your data in `Legended[data, label]`, but in that case whatever is in `label` will be used to label `data` in the plot.  Normally you would put something like "dataset 1" there, instead of a complete and placed legend.

Perhaps one of these will work:

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[1, {4, 2}],
    Joined -> True,
    PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{Directive[Thick]}, {"legend"}], {Right, Top}]
]
```

[image]

Or here, apply the style to the plot, and then the line legend will match the plot

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[1, {4, 2}],
    Joined -> True,
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick],
    PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"legend"}], {Right, Top}]
]
```

[image]

This produces the same output, but maybe with syntax more to your liking

```
ListPlot[Legended[RandomReal[1, {4, 2}],"legend"],
    Joined -> True,
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick],
    PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {Right, Top}]
]
```

Comment: According to the document one can put `Placed[...]` in the `label` section (the neat example), and that's necessary to style the legend. I know I can use `PlotLegends` for a single plot but I'm still curious why the example works and my code fails.

Comment: Your code doesn't fail, it does exactly what you are asking it to do.  In your code, replace `LineLegend[....]` with `"legend"` and see what the result is, and it should make sense why your code behaves like it does.